# Magento 1.9.1 Notifications (Emails, Newsletters) not send

Tags: email-reminders

I am having Magento 1.9.1 with cron setup and triggered fine! When i place a new order i am not receiving any emails (not admin not customer). I have tried all possible commands:

```
*/5 * * * * /bin/sh MAGENTO_PATH/cron.sh
*/5 * * * * /bin/bash MAGENTO_PATH/cron.sh
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php MAGENTO_PATH/cron.php
*/5 * * * * /usr/local/bin/php -f MAGENTO_PATH/cron.php
```

Do the .sh script need any modification?? Do i miss anything else?

Comment: Not need in modification

Comment: Are your other cron jobs working? Are there erros in the log files?

Comment: are you getting the original order emails as these are not sent via cron

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue.
I guess its bug from Magento 1.8~1.9.1.

Try this.
Open the file cron.php in the root directory of Magento and look for (around line 47):

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, ‘win’) === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

After this line, add:

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

Save the file. After a couple minutes the cron should start working.

Thanks for the source:
http://support.xtento.com/wiki/Setting_up_the_Magento_cronjob

From this I fixed the newsletter and for emails use this extension:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html